# Flash Videos are not working in FireFox

Tags: firefox, video, google-chrome

FaceBook videos through FireFox do not play properly. If I am using Chromium the sound runs but the frame rate is only one per second! QupZilla fails with a JavaScript problem. Trying to run QuickTime Videos on my machine result in a Mu-Law decoder needed. Therefore no sound plays. But VLC Media Player will play them?
`ubuntu-restrcted-extras` did nothing or made it worse.

Comment: It may not install those things by default. You may also need (want) to add universe and multiverse. To do that you want to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Then the Ubuntu Software Center should give you the option to install Flash and all sorts of QT like libraries (gstreamer).

Comment: Why not try "chrome" downloaded from google.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Ubuntu Restricted Extras package using the command

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Installing this package will pull in support for MP3 playback and decoding, support for various other audio formats (GStreamer plugins), Microsoft fonts, Flash plugin, LAME (to create compressed audio files), and DVD playback.

Comment: Ok thanks I am new to this. I found A "restricted - extras" In the software. It said I have to remove some thing I can't remember right now. The first and last time I hade to use command line was 1983.

Comment: Alexis Wilke, Thanks for the try. First how do I get the command line window to show up? Then I went to the ubuntu software centre and searched. Nothing makes sence. I un-installed both browsers reinstalled them. NG installed all sorts of LIB for QT??? Type in the search box OXIDENT Codecs and installed a bunch there also. Now the Firefox works but some times locks up and Chromium doesn't play QT or Flash Videos at all.

Comment: Nice try. I spent two days trying to get eather browser to work. I don't know how to use command line. So I installed ubuntu=restricted-extras. Lib's for QT. all the ident and oxident codecs. I uninstalled boath browsers, aand reinstalled them. neather will work compleatly. FireFox played some videos and won't show the controles for anothwer video player. The Chromium  just said not supported, and won't run anything. So I gave up. I downloaded QupZilla, and it seems to work.

Comment: Well not intirly. I still cant get QuickTime videos to work.

Comment: I have reloaded FireFox used coomand line this time and seems to have been sucesful except for a locked file that is not needed. so here we go again. Trying FF.

Comment: If a file is not needed why can I not remove it? NG still not playing.I wonder, is there a deference? When you ask the softwair center for "ubuntu-restricted-extras" and "Xubuntu-restricted-extras"?

Comment: How do I get Adobe Flash Player? to work properly in any of these web browsers? Now when in Chromium most videos play back at one frame per second. And in QupZilla and FireFox it says plugin needed.

Comment: Hello, Is this question closed? I can't accept an answer that does not work? Anyone, what am I not understanding here?

Comment: Hello any one home? This was started a month ago and has been viewed over 200 times and I have no response? What an I not understanding here?

Comment: I still can not get a video to work in Chromium and FireFox.And I tryed 4 other browsers. nothing runs videos.